# discord bot. database. embed doesn't appear

Tags: database, discord, bots, embed

I want my bot react to a command.
If ?2 print line 2 of database
?3 print line 3 of database
etc...
I don't know why my embed doesn't appear I have no console errors...
My bot is connected and respond. My database is ok

```
    if message.content.startswith('$'):
        arg_id = message.content

        conn = None
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        req = conn.cursor()
        req.execute("SELECT * FROM space2 WHERE id=?", (arg_id,))
        rows = req.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            embed = discord.Embed(title='test', color=0x0000FF)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/231-2316751_database-database-icon-png.png')
            embed.add_field(name='id', value=row[0], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='CATEGORIE', value=row[1], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='RANK', value=row[2], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='SCORE', value=row[3], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='POWER AREA GRAVITY 0', value=row[4], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='POWER EYES WEAPONS', value=row[5], inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
            msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            print(row)
```

NEW VERSION

there are advances but still mistakes...a little help would be appreciated...thanks

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$'):
        message_slices = message.content.split()
        try:
            arg_id = int(message_slices[0][1:])
        except ValueError:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Invalid argument", color=0x0000FF)
            embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            conn = None
            try:
                conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
            except Error as e:
                print(e)
                exit(-1)

            req = conn.cursor()

            try:
                req.execute("SELECT * FROM space2 WHERE id=?", (arg_id,))
            except Error as e:
                print(e)
            else:
                row = req.fetchone()
                if row is not None:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title='NFT', color=0x0000FF)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/231-2316751_database-database-icon-png.png')
                    embed.add_field(name='id', value=str(row[0]), inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name='CATEGORIE', value=str(row[1]), inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name='RANK', value=str(row[2]), inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name='SCORE', value=str(row[3]), inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name='POWER AREA GRAVITY 0', value=str(row[4]), inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name='POWER EYES WEAPONS', value=str(row[5]), inline=False)
                    embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                else:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Not found", color=0x0000FF)
                    embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

            req.close()
            conn.close()```
    enter code here
````

Comment: There are no rows returned most likely

Comment: Yes there are advances but still mistakes...
I edited my post with new version...
a little help would be appreciated...thanks